# Collect items from an iterator at a specific index

Tags: rust

I was wondering if it is possible to use `.collect()` on an iterator to grab items at a specific index. For example if I start with a string, I would normally do:

```
let line = "Some line of text for example";
let l = line.split(" ");
let lvec: Vec<&str> = l.collect();
let text = &lvec[3];
```

But what would be nice is something like:

```
let text: &str = l.collect(index=(3));
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, it's not; however you can easily *filter* before you *collect*, which in practice achieves the same effect.

If you wish to filter by index, you need to add the index in and then strip it afterwards:

- `enumerate` (to add the index to the element)
- `filter` based on this index
- `map` to strip the index from the element

Or in code:

```
fn main() {
    let line = "Some line of text for example";
    let l = line.split(" ")
                .enumerate()
                .filter(|&(i, _)| i == 3 )
                .map(|(_, e)| e);
    let lvec: Vec<&str> = l.collect();
    let text = &lvec[0];
    println!("{}", text);
}
```

If you only wish to get a single index (and thus element), then using `nth` is much easier. It returns an `Option<&str>` here, which you need to take care of:

```
fn main() {
    let line = "Some line of text for example";
    let text = line.split(" ").nth(3).unwrap();
    println!("{}", text);
}
```

If you can have an arbitrary predicate but wishes only the first element that matches, then collecting into a `Vec` is inefficient: it will consume the whole iterator (no laziness) and allocate potentially a lot of memory that is not needed at all.

You are thus better off simply asking for the first element using the `find_map` method of the iterator, which returns an `Option<&str>` here:

```
fn main() {
    let line = "Some line of text for example";
    let text = line.split(" ")
                   .enumerate()
                   .find_map(|(i, e)| (i % 7 == 3).then_some(e))
                   .unwrap();
    println!("{}", text);
}
```

If you want to select *part* of the result, by index, you may also use `skip` and `take` before collecting, but I guess you have enough alternatives presented here already.

Comment: Thank you, a lot to take in here but very useful. You mentioned that collecting into a Vec is inefficient. Would you be able to comment on the speed of performing line.split.enumerate.filter.map.unwrap multiple times to grab different items from the string vs collecting the whole thing into a Vec and then using vector indexing to retrieve items. As a rule of thumb for example, if a need to access 1/4 of the items, which method do I go for?

Comment: @kezzos: I mentioned that collecting *everything* into a vector was inefficient, and I also gave the reasons: iterating up until the end when you don't care about the last pieces and allocating memory. If you need to collect 1/4 of the pieces, then I would not worry about the memory allocation, however you may still gain from cutting the iteration short (using `take`).

Comment: There's also [`filter_map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) to combine the `filter` and `map` steps.

Answer (score 28):

There is a `nth` function on `Iterator` that does this:

```
let text = line.split(" ").nth(3).unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks, does this also return an Option<&str>?

Comment: Sure, that's what the `unwrap` is for. It's basically `fn unwrap(x : Option<T>) { if let Some(v) = x { v } else { panic!("Meh") } }`.

Answer (score 2):

No; you can use `take` and `next`, though:

```
let line = "Some line of text for example";
let l = line.split(" ");
let text = l.skip(3).next();
```

Note that this results in `text` being an `Option<&str>`, as there's no guarantee that the sequence actually *has* at least four elements.

**Addendum**: using `nth` is definitely shorter, though I prefer to be explicit about the fact that accessing the *n*<sup>th</sup> element of an iterator necessarily *consumes* all the elements before it.

Comment: Regarding your addendum, I see your point. However, rust is pretty explicit anyhow: If you write it in a single line it's fine anyhow because you will not use the (partially consumed) split anywhere else. If you want to split the splitting and getting the 4th item, the compiler will force you to write `let mut l = line.split(" ")` to be able to use `nth`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who may be interested, you can can do loads of cool things with iterators (thanks Matthieu M), for example to get multiple 'words' from a string according to their index, you can use `filter` along with logical or `||` to test for multiple indexes !

```rust
let line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062"
let words: Vec<&str> = line.split(" ")
                           .enumerate()
                           .filter(|&(i, _)| i==1 || i==3 || i==6 )
                           .map(|(_, e) | e)
                           .collect();
```